# Reusing old C# classes with new Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, content-management-system, orchardcms

I currently have some modules written in C# to post data onto my Facebook page as well as send some sms based on the input on the website which is written in asp.

Is there anyway i could reuse my classes written in C# to be used in orchard cms? I have tried to google some facebook modules written for FB but they are largely towards connecting to the CMS via facebook.

I would just need to post some updates on Facebook based on the information entered into my CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, Orchard is an ASP.NET MVC application. If you can reuse your code in a plain ASP.NET MVC app then you can reuse it in Orchard as well.

Answer (score 0):

Orchard has in 1.7 the workflow module (or the rules module for older versions). Using these you can set up events that occur on publish, for example. Using these you can send updates to Facebook or whatever you want really. You should be able to reuse some of your C#, the publishing to Facebook parts at least. There are plenty of examples in Orchards source code of how to use the Workflows module if you just have a look for them.

Good luck